# Select all nodes that reference the current node

Tags: nodes

I'm new to Drupal and am wondering if anyone could provide direction on this.

Basically I have 2 content types - one called 'clinics' and one called 'clinic groups'. Each 'clinic' has a node-reference to a 'clinic group' node. What I'm trying to achieve is basically, if I'm on the 'clinic group' page - I'd like to pull back all the nodes 'clinics' under it, that reference it.

Is this possible in views?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using views.Create a view where under

```
Fields you select your group as Node, Under that choose Title.

For Filters select Node Type, Operator: Is one of and select Clinic content type.

Under Arguments select your group as Content. Under that choose Clinic_group (the node reference field).
```

You can add additional parameters to your view like Number of items to display, more fields like Node: Body and maybe a filter that Node: Published, select yes.

To see a preview, under live preview give the arguments as node number and click Preview.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works with Views by itself, but the [Node Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships) module uses customized views for output.